# Hold data in model post refresh in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there any way out to hold data in the model even after refresh the page in AngularJS.

Comment: You can store data across refreshes in window.localStorage

Comment: ... or sessionStorage, if that makes more sense. Otherwise, no - when you refresh the page, the Angular app reloads, thus resetting all the models